# How to delete table from layout in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to find a way to switch between tables that are loaded from SQL. I want to completely remove one table from the page before loading the next one.
Thanks!

```
class DisplayLog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DisplayLog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QGridLayout()

        self.inTbl =QTableView()
        self.outTbl =QTableView()

        # push button 2
        IncomingButton = UIFunctions._AddButton("Display Incoming")
        OutgoingButton = UIFunctions._AddButton("Display Outgoing")
        PaintButton = UIFunctions._AddButton("Display Paint")
        IncomingButton.clicked.connect(self.incoming_display)  # Call function when clicked
        OutgoingButton.clicked.connect(self.outgoing_display)  # Call function when clicked

        self.layout.addWidget(IncomingButton, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(OutgoingButton, 0, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(PaintButton, 0, 2)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def incoming_display(self):
        if createConnection():
            sql = 'SELECT * FROM IncomingCoilTable'
            self.inTbl = displayData(sql)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.inTbl, 1, 1)

    def outgoing_display(self):
        self.layout.removeWidget(self.inTbl)
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layout is a member function of QWidget, you're overwriting it.

Comment: How would I overwrite a table then?

Comment: @jeremykleiber Passerby was referring to the fact that you should not overwrite `self.layout` (which is a function) with your layout (which is an instance). Besides that, if you want to switch between models, just use a single QTableView and then use [`setModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setModel) with the different models. Otherwise, use a [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html)